# Puma bind_to tcp not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, puma

I changed the puma setting in deploy.rb from

```
set :puma_bind, "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/puma.sock"
```

to

```
set :puma_bind, "tcp://0.0.0.0:3000"
```

After deployment with capistrano it still seems to use the socket configuration.

htop output:

```
28003 ?        Sl     0:02 puma 3.4.0 (unix:///home/deploy/portal/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock) [20160718080852]
```

puma log:

```
=== puma startup: 2016-07-18 08:09:56 +0000 ===
* Inherited unix:///home/deploy/portal/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock
```

Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using the `capistrano3-puma` gem. Make sure you run `cap production puma:config` to update the Puma configuration on the server. Then redeploy.

Comment: That was exactly what was missing. I thought that restarting puma will read out the new configuration. Thanks a lot!